# Add break line in custom message for ADB2C first sign in password validation

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

i try to custom my password validation message for my ADB2C first sign in. I read the doc (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-language-customization) and i'm able to add a custom message, but when i try to add break line it doesn't work. I tried adding \n or 
, but nothing works

Someone know how to make it work?

the custom message:

```
{
  "ElementType": "ClaimType",
  "ElementId": "newPassword",
  "StringId": "PatternHelpText",
  "Override": true,
  "Value": "8-16 characters <br> containing 3 out of 4 of the following: \n Lowercase characters, uppercase characters, digits (0-9), and one or more of the following symbols: @ # $ % ^ & * - _ + = [ ] { } | \\ : ' , ? / ` ~ \" ( ) ; ."
},
```

[image: customTextResult]

Answer (score 0):

Language customization doesn't allow for HTML content. It only allows for "safe strings".

Alternatively, you can add [custom JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-javascript-overview), which replaces the default content for the `div.error.itemLevel` element with the custom content for it.